# Playing WMA files with cmus produces static and distortion in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, music, wma, cmus

I use cmus as a media player and after upgrading to 14.04, all WMA files in my collection have become unplayable. When I try playing them, I get static in my left speaker and a staticky distorted version of the music in my right speaker.

How can I fix this issue? Maybe have cmus use a different codec for wma? (WMA files still play fine in mplayer.)

Comment: Just WMA? do other formats (.oog, .mp4) play alright? Do the .wma work with other music players ?

Comment: I will have to check on other formats, but (written above) WMA files play fine in mplayer.

Comment: If wmp play with mplayer, but not cmus, I suspect a cmus bug

Comment: I played an OGG file just fine, but had the same problem with an MP4 with AAC audio.

Comment: An alternative is to use ffmpeg to convert .m4a files to .mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is apparently related to the libavcodec/ffmpeg fork: https://github.com/cmus/cmus/issues/139

I fixed cmus by installing libswresample-dev and the rest of the ffmpeg dev libs from this PPA (replacing the libavcodec libs):

https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg

Then `./configure CONFIG_FFMPEG=y` to make sure that ffmpeg.c works and building and replacing cmus.

Comment: Repo no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by going to https://github.com/cmus/cmus and compiling the program from source..  I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS...